# How to get localized day-names in django?

Tags: python, django, localization, calendar, internationalization

When using djangos (or better gettext's) localization mechanism, it's hard to get the current locale's day names. Usually, i would use `calendar`:

```
calendar.day_name[current_day]
```

Where `current_day` is a int between 0 and 6. This won't work, as Django does not seem to set the requested locale correctly. Same situation for month names.

So, how to localize calendar-names correctly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `django.utils.formats.date_format`.

```
>>> from django.utils.formats import date_format
>>> from django.utils import translation
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date_format(date.today(), 'l')
'Saturday'
>>> translation.activate('fr')
>>> date_format(date.today(), 'l')
'samedi'
```

`translation.activate` is useless in the context of a request where translation is already activated. I used it here for example purpose.

If you don't have a specific date and need the name of a day of the week, just use gettext to translate it:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> from django.utils import translation
>>> from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
>>> translation.activate('fr')
>>> _(calendar.day_name[0])
'lundi'
```

Note that the reason why `_(day_name)` works, although "day_name" is a variable, is because [day names are already translated by Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1a60838/django/conf/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po#L898-L917), and thus don't need to be discovered by gettext.

Comment: Warning: If you don't have the day name elsewhere explicitly in gettext, then it won't be collected by running `manage.py makemessages` command which will result in yielding non-translated string.

Comment: @KryštofŘeháček Wrong. You don't need to have day names defined elsewhere in your own code as it's already defined by Django: [utils/dates.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/648957b/django/utils/dates.py#L6-L7) [conf/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1a60838/django/conf/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po#L898-L899)

Comment: Ok, you are right. But I still want to encourage people to avoid this pattern since it's built on the assumption that Django defines it and it's not universal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `different_locale` from `calendar` to return a localized day name:

```
from calendar import day_name, different_locale

def get_localized_day_name(day, locale):
    with different_locale(locale):
        return day_name[day]
```

`locale` is a string that contains your desired locale, e.g. `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`.